# Return a regular array from array list

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

So I have this method that I need to return all objects of an array list. But cant figure out how (I dont even know if I should be using an array list).

The issue is I'm going to have an unknown number of objects that need to be passed in one return statement. So I currently have them stored into the array list called tables.

Here is my code:

```
public GuestTable[] GetSeatingChart(String filename) {
    GuestTable table1 = new GuestTable();
    GuestTable table2 = new GuestTable();
    GuestTable table3 = new GuestTable();

    table1.AddGuestToTable(47);
    table2.AddGuestToTable(53);
    table3.AddGuestToTable(53);

    tables.add(table1);
    tables.add(table2);
    tables.add(table3);

    return new GuestTable[] {tables.get()}; 
}
```

My issues is at the

```
return new GuesTable[] {tables.get()};
```

Arraylists don't have a `getAll()` function so I'm kind of stuck. Since the number of elements in the array list aka the number of tables will be different every time I cant just use something static in the return statement.

This project is for a final project and I'm newer to programming.

-Thanks Mike

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#toArray-T:A-

Comment: What you trying to return in your code is an array not a list. Please check internet to see how to use arrayList.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ArrayList`has a method:

```
toArray(T[] arr);
```

So you can easily make use of it:

```
GuestTable[] tablesArray = new GuestTable[tables.size()];
tables.toArray(tablesArray);
return tablesArray;
```

Or you can simply change method signature to return `ArrayLists`:

```
public ArrayList<GuestTable> GetSeatingChart(String filename) {
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I'm sure it was a really dumb question but now I know.